# Self-elevating VBS from mapped network drive not working

Tags: vbscript

Here is my sample test code:

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim localServiceKey : localServiceKey = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKEY_USERS\s-1-5-19\")
'On error, elevate the script
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName, """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1
    Err.Clear
    WScript.Quit()
End If

...INSERT CODE BELOW...
```

This self-elevating VBS script file works properly if I run it from a local drive or from a network drive accessed using UNC (ie: **\\server\folder**).

But if I run it from a mapped drive (ie: **Z:\folder**), I receive an error after the UAC prompt stating:

> Can not find script file...

Is there a work around for allowing VBS script file to run from a mapped network drive?

NOTE:  I'm testing this code on Windows 10 x64.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: A network drive mapping is a per-user setting. For you as user, the `Z:\\` is mapped, but since the script is rerun using another user (administrator), your mapping does not apply.